# Bootstrap .justify-content-center not centering applied divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have tried to place a search form into 2 parent divs. Whether I try the align or justify utility neither of them are able to center the search bar in the middle of the page, where I want it.

```
<div class="col">
  <div class"container-fluid justify-content-center" id="searchform">
    <form class="form-floating form-control-sm" id="form">
      <div class="row " id="div_main">
        <div class="col-auto " id="div_Location">
          <label for="Location">Hunt Location</label><br>
          <select name="cars" id="Location">
            <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
            <option value="Western Cape">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="Northern Cape">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="North West">North West</option>
            <option value="Limpopo">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="Free State">Free State</option>
            <option value="Mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
            <option value="Eastern cape">Eastern Cape</option>
            <option value="Kwa-zulu Natal">kwa-zulu Natal</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Animal">
          <label for="Animal">Animal</label><br>
          <select name="Animals" id="Animal">
            <option value="" id="ListAnimal"></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Check-in">
          <label for="Check-in">Check-in</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Check-in" placeholder="Check-in" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Check-out">
          <label for="floatingInputValue">Check-out</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Check-out" placeholder="Check-out" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Hunters">
          <label for="Hunters">Hunters</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Hunters" placeholder="5" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark d-iline" id="searchbutton"><img src="img/search.png"></img></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but it's usually not necessary to use additional `.container` elements inside columns.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `col` is to take up 100% of the available space, so `justify-content-center` won't have any meaningful effect as the column is already at a width of 100% and cannot be centered relative to the parent container.

If we clean up your code the results you expect can be achieved fairly easily (Note: You will need to run this snippet full screen to see it centered).

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto" id="search-form">

      <form class="form-floating form-control-sm" id="form">
      
      <div class="form-row" id="div_main">
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Location">
          <label for="Location">Hunt Location</label><br>
          <select name="cars" id="Location" class="custom-select">
            <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
            <option value="Western Cape">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="Northern Cape">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="North West">North West</option>
            <option value="Limpopo">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="Free State">Free State</option>
            <option value="Mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
            <option value="Eastern cape">Eastern Cape</option>
            <option value="Kwa-zulu Natal">kwa-zulu Natal</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Animal">
          <label for="Animal">Animal</label><br>
          <select name="Animals" id="Animal"  class="custom-select">
            <option value="" id="ListAnimal"></option>
          </select>
        </div>
       
       <div class="col-auto" id="div_Check-in">
          <label for="Check-in">Check-in</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Check-in" placeholder="Check-in" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Check-out">
          <label for="floatingInputValue">Check-out</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Check-out" placeholder="Check-out" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto" id="div_Hunters">
          <label for="Hunters">Hunters</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Hunters" placeholder="5" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto align-self-end">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="searchbutton">Search</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

First I've applied the correct Grid components of `container-fluid` and `row` to make sure that everything is lined up as one would expect within Bootstrap. You may have omitted that for brevity but I wanted to make sure it was shown.

Changing `.col` to `.col-auto` will allow the form's parent element to take up only as much width as needed, which will allow `justify-content-center` to center the column when applied to `row`.

> If you don't want to apply that class to the row wrapper, you can apply `mx-auto` to the `col-auto` wrapper.

A couple of house-keeping notes:

- As isherwood stated in the comments, your original use of an additional `container` element is not needed, and is in fact frowned upon as it can result in unexpected issues.
- The `<img>` tag is self-closing, meaning you should format it either as `<img src="..." />` or without the self-closing slash.  `</img>` does not exist.